# Using https with Django

Tags: django, https, foursquare

I am running Django on an AWS EC2 instance.

I am receiving checkin POSTS from the Foursquare API. Foursquare requires an https address to send the POST to (but the certificate doesn't have to be signed).

How do I get HTTPS to work with Django? I get the sense that I'm going to need another server, like Apache. If this is the case, I know very little about Apache and find most answer confusing.

I only need the https for this one case. What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Apache is not a requirement, then you can use another server, for example NGINX. There is a tutorial [for getting NGINX running on an EC2 environment](http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_setup_development_environment_on_ec2.html). The reason I am suggesting NGINX is because it's been performing better (note: I did compare with `ab` but don't take my word for it).

Once you have NGINX running you can configure it to use SSL; here is [the documentation to do so](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html). The reason why you need something like NGINX is because python isn't the best for all types of requests (e.g. for media / static files). You may also need NGINX to hand off the request to a WSGI handler (e.g. `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`). You can [read more about that here](https://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn).

If the SSL certificate does not have to be signed you can create a self-signed certificate, here is [an example of tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) where you can stop after the step that creates the certificate (or if you want to use Apache, proceed with all the steps).

Some good tutorials:

- Here is a ["Start to finish - Serving django with iwsgi/nginx on EC2"](http://adambard.com/blog/start-to-finish-serving-mysql-backed-django-w/).
- Here is one for [Django Nginx Gunicorn MySQL/Postgres stack on a single Amazon EC2](https://gist.github.com/sgarcez/2649467).

EDIT: to handle both `http` and `https`:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do I specify that port 443 should be "forwarded" to 80? Or is that implied.